# Matplotlib plot/scatter wrong non-linear y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
list(reversed(best_cs.precisions))

['0.0269',
 '0.0318',
 '0.0600',
 '0.0949',
 '0.1227',
 '0.1324',
 '0.1822',
 '0.2426',
 '0.3624',
 '0.4258',
 '0.4876']

recalls
[1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0]
```

And then when I try to plot it with line or scatter plot I get a strange y-axis:

[image]

Comment: Probably because your y-values are strings. Try convert to float: `[float(i) for i in list(reversed(best_cs.precisions))]`

Comment: Yes that must be it :)